# How do I change the scrolling speed?

Tags: 7

I recently installed and enabled the [Back To Top](https://www.drupal.org/project/back_to_top) module. It gives a button at right bottom of the screen to scroll back to the top of the page.

How can I increase the scrolling speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file [`back_to_top/js/back_to_top.js`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/back_to_top/tree/js/back_to_top.js) you'll find the following on line 23:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1200, 'easeOutQuart', function() {
```

The 1200 is the animation duration in milliseconds. Lower it and the animation will go faster. Optionally you could raise a feature request in the module issue queue to make this a configurable setting.